# Getting Firestore data as Javascript object

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to get the data from Google Firestore as a javascript object in Vue.js (3).
It works perfectly when using the data in a V-for, but I want to use the array in methods aswell.
How do I turn this data from Firestore into a simple Javascript object?
I've tried using `JSON.parse()` but that doesn't work.

This is the Data I get:
[image: Screenshot of the raw data from Firestore]

Using this code:

```html
<template>
  <section>
    <div id="testWrapper">
        <div>
            <p>{{ list }}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</template>

<script>
import { useLoadClients } from "../../firebase.js";


export default {
    data(){
        return{
            list:[]
        }

    },
    async mounted(){
        const newList = await useLoadClients()
        this.list= newList
    }
}
</script>
```

This is the Firebase config (obviously is censored the Api key):

```html
import firebase from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/firestore";
import { ref, onUnmounted } from "vue";

const config = {
  apiKey: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  authDomain: "hourly-3295e.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL:
    "https://hourly-3295e-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app",
  projectId: "hourly-3295e",
  storageBucket: "hourly-3295e.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "434096768140",
  appId: "1:434096768140:web:16bca36e806af1d7e027a9",
  measurementId: "G-XMHZQHM81H",
};

const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(config);

const db = firebaseApp.firestore();
const clientCollection = db.collection("clients");

export const createClient = (client) => {
  return clientCollection.add(client);
};

export const getClient = async (id) => {
  const user = await clientCollection.doc(id).get();
  return user.exists ? user.data() : null;
};

export const updateClient = (id, client) => {
  return clientCollection.doc(id).update(client);
};

export const deleteClient = (id) => {
  return clientCollection.doc(id).delete();
};

export const useLoadClients = () => {
  const clients = ref([]);
  const close = clientCollection.onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
    clients.value = snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({ id: doc.id, ...doc.data() }));
  });
  onUnmounted(close);
  return clients;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Snapshot.data() is already a Javascript object, your app is rendering it as text since you are printing it in a text element.
Should you still need to convert it from text to an object, you can use `JSON.parse(jsonString)`

I also highly recommend using `typeof snapshot.data()` which will return a string value of its type, in this case `"string"` or `"Object"` respectfully.